# Calculate the next event from now given an NSDate in the past and a repeat interval

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsdate, date-arithmetic

How can I calculate the first date later than now from a date in the past by repeating a certain interval? For example:

```
// Date in the past
NSDate *pastDate = [NSDate my_dateWithString:@"11/09/2001"];

// Time interval
NSTimeInterval repeatInterval = 14 * 24 * 60 * 60; // 2 weeks

// Current date
NSDate *now = [NSDate date]; // 23/07/2015

// Start calculating next date ->
NSDate *nextDate = /* interval added to past date */
// Is result later than now?
// No? Calculate again
// Abracadabra

NSLog(@"nexDate = %@",nextDate); // 28/07/2015
```

I don't want to use iterations. I'm concerned about calculating a case like a start date one year in the past and a repeat interval of a day.

Here is my solution, but it has iterations.

```
  NSDateComponents *twoWeeksDateComponents = [NSDateComponents new];
  twoWeeksDateComponents.weekOfMonth = 2;

  NSDate *date = self.picker.date;
  NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

  NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
  NSDate *nextDate = date;
  NSComparisonResult result = [nextDate compare:now];
  while (result == NSOrderedAscending) {
    nextDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:kTwoWeeksDateComponents
                                         toDate:nextDate
                                        options:NSCalendarMatchNextTime];
    result = [nextDate compare:now];
  }
  NSLog(@"nexDate = %@",nextDate); // 28/07/2015
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed do this without iteration, using a little arithmetic instead. You're looking for the nearest multiple of some factor *f* strictly greater than another value *n*. It's a bit more complicated being a calendrical calculation, but still just arithmetic (and `NSCalendar` of course does all the heavy lifting for you -- e.g., leap years).

```
NSDate * pastDate = ...;
NSDate * now = [NSDate date];
```

Get your repeat interval however you like from the user and construct an `NSDateComponents` representing it:

```
NSCalendarUnit repeatUnit = NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear;
NSUInteger repeatInterval = 2;

NSDateComponents * repeatComps = [NSDateComponents new];
[repeatComps setValue:repeatInterval forComponent:repeatUnit];
```

Given the repeat unit, find the amount of that unit that occurs between the two dates, as another date components object:

```
NSCalendar * cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents * deltaComps = [cal components:repeatUnit
                                       fromDate:pastDate
                                         toDate:now
                                        options:0];
NSInteger deltaVal = [deltaComps valueForComponent:repeatUnit];
```

Now comes the arithmetical bit. Round the delta down to the nearest multiple of the repeat interval. Then adding that rounded value (using the appropriate unit) will produce a date equal to or earlier than now.

Now, as jawboxer [has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596749/calculate-the-next-event-from-now-given-an-nsdate-in-the-past-and-a-repeat-inter/31598663#comment53742464_31598663), for a `repeatUnit` of `NSCalendarUnitMonth`, you get unexpected results if you calculate the date using that value and afterwards add one more repeat interval (as the original version of this answer did). Instead, add one to the number of repeats immediately; then the calendar correctly handles month increments.

```
NSInteger repeatsJustPastNow = 1 + deltaVal - (deltaVal % repeatInterval);

NSDateComponents * toNowComps = [NSDateComponents new];
[toNowComps setValue:repeatsJustPastNow
        forComponent:repeatUnit];

NSDate * nextDate;
nextDate = [cal dateByAddingComponents:toNowComps
                                toDate:pastDate
                               options:0];
```

Jawboxer's [Swift version of this corrected code is on Github](https://gist.github.com/jim-rhoades/ea0c5b241ec77a37f86b).

Comment: Ended up posting mine before seeing yours... would it be OK to use mine (it seems to always return the right date, preserves time and works on crazy intervals like 1 week + 1 day + 3 hours + 4 minutes)? Or should I go through date components rather than just doing math on the interval?

Comment: Your version can't cope very easily with repeat units of months or years. Try using a start date of 2015-03-01 and an interval of 1 year, for example. `NSCalendar` accounts for the leap day in 2016.

Comment: `NSDateComponents` can handle compound intervals, as well.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thanks. :)

Comment: Sure thing, @Metabble.

Comment: Hey, I'm back. I tested our versions and my version is faster: myDuration: 0.336574 s, joshDuration: 2.40654 s. About results my version give wrong result when today recurrence of date occur. I tried with 100k random dates and wrong result is just in this case.

Comment: There's no way that this code takes 2.4 _seconds_ to run.

Comment: This is great, but I think I've found a flaw. Assuming `pastDate` is January 31, 2015, your `repeatUnit` is monthly, and `now` is March 15, 2015 - the result ends up being March 28, 2015 (rather than the expected result of March 31). Would it be better to add 1 to `repeatsToNow` and get `nextDate` from that, like I do in [this example (in Swift)](https://gist.github.com/jawboxer/ea0c5b241ec77a37f86b)? My modified version does give the expected March 31 result, but maybe there was some other reason for the way you did it?

Comment: Interesting, @Jawboxer; I'll look into it when I get a chance.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @Jawboxer; I've incorporated your fix and linked to your Swift gist.

Comment: I think I have found yet another bug in above snippet. Instead of statically adding `1` to `repeatPastJustNow`, it should be adding `repeatInterval`. If you change the `repeatInterval` to 3 or 4 etc. the code would not produce expected result. Here is the updated [source code](https://gist.github.com/sethi-ishmeet/4614554fdf428c1ca14d3f02797d3e0c). Also updated for Swift 5.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As Josh pointed out this doesn't account for leap years. So this is a good example of an implementation that might seem to work over short term testing but has holes in it. It also will be off by some hours in the log as `dateFromString:` will compensate for timezone while the log will log it as GMT.

---

```
NSDateFormatter* format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
format.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm";
NSDate *pastDate = [format dateFromString:  @"2001-09-11 at 00:00"];

NSTimeInterval repeatInterval = 14 * 24 * 60 * 60; // 2 weeks

NSDate *nowDate = [NSDate date];

NSTimeInterval timeFromPastDate = [nowDate timeIntervalSinceDate: pastDate];
NSTimeInterval modulus = timeFromPastDate / repeatInterval;
modulus -= floor(modulus);

NSDate *nextDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval: repeatInterval * (1 - modulus) sinceDate: nowDate];

NSLog(@"nexDate = %@",nextDate); // 28th/July/2015, if current date is 23rd/July/2015
```

Answer (score 0):

I made another solution early.

```
  NSDate *date = ...;

  static NSTimeInterval k2WeeksInterval = 14 * 24 * 60 * 60.0;

  NSTimeInterval timeInterval = -date.timeIntervalSinceNow;

  double repeats = ceil(timeInterval / k2WeeksInterval);

  NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

  NSDateComponents *components = [NSDateComponents new];
  components.weekOfYear = repeats * 2;

  NSDate *nextDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components
                                               toDate:date
                                              options:NSCalendarMatchNextTime];
```

Comment: [Like Metabble's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596749/calculate-the-next-event-from-now-given-an-nsdate-in-the-past-and-a-repeat-inter#comment51149875_31598663), this doesn't handle months or years particularly well.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, I guess this will works well, because NSTimeInterval is a double value and calculation about how much repeats give me true result, but calculations about leap year NSCalendar will calculate for me. :)

Comment: Need tests, but your answer is exactly what I need, thank you :) P.S. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Glad I could help, @Igor.